# Masonry view showing images one below another

Tags: html, ajax, angularjs, web-deployment, jquery-masonry

I have used a Masonry view plugin but when the images load through the ajax call, they seem to be displayed one below another (like a list)

HTML

```
    <div id="masonryView" data-ng-repeat="image in images">
            <div class="item">
              <a target="_blank" href="">
                <img src="{{image.imageSourceURL}}" alt="" width="250">
              </a>
              <div class="desc">{image.description}</div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Ajax

```
  $(window).load(function(){
    var $container = $('#masonryView').masonry();
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
    $container.masonry();
    });
  });
```

CSS

```
#masonryView {
 position: relative;
}

.item {
   margin: 10px;
   width: 100px; 
 }
```

Does there seem to be a problem that could explain why the images are displayed one below another?

Comment: Try this plugin if you are using angular js https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry

Comment: It worked!! Just additional thing was to include imagesLoaded dependency that took a lot of time to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing any AJAX in your posted code labeled "AJAX" but you should call masonry in this way, by setting your itemSelector:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var $container = $('#masonryView').masonry();
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
$container.masonry({itemSelector: '.item'});
});
});
```

Comment: I tried this but the imagesLoaded still does not work.

Comment: As you stated above, you needed to add it.

Comment: Is there any plugin available for popping out the images inside masonry view after click. And additionally to scroll the images by pressing the left or right arrow?